# JPA failed to automatically generate a table from an entity

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, derby

I am using Eclipselink with Derby database to automatically generated a database from Entities.

The generation worked just fine at first, but when i added a User entity to my model and tried to generate tables from entities with JPA tools all the tables are generated except the User table & i get the following error during the generation

```
[EL Warning]: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "USER" at line 1, column 14.
Error Code: 30000
```

This is the user entity

```
@NamedQuery( name = "User.findByUsername", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.username = :userneme AND u.password = :password" )
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Transient
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public User() {
        super();
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
    private Integer id;

    private String  username;
    private String  password;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername( String username ) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword( String password ) {
        this.password = password;
    }
```

Can anyone tell me why i am getting the exception ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table name is `"USER"` which is a reserved keyword in SQL (and in Apache Derby). Some JPA providers (e.g DataNucleus JPA) automatically quote such keywords for you meaning it would just work. Others (e.g EclipseLink) don't and so you have to explicitly set the table name with surrounding quote marks (') or set the table name to something that is not a SQL keyword

```
@Table(name="'User'")
public class User {...}
```

Comment: It doesn't work by adding the quote marks .. it did by changing the name completely .. Thanks for the reply

Comment: AFAIK, you have to use either double quotes  - `@Table(name="\"User\"")` - or backticks - `@Table(name="\`User\`")`, but not single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

This most likely is because USER is a function in the Derby Database (Refer this : http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/ref/rrefsqlj42476.html). You possibly can have  the JPA bean as User , but specify a different table name using @Table annotation

Comment: I am using Derby not H2 database but it worked with Derby to .. Thank you